# ERROR "The named parameter 'auth' is required, but there's no corresponding argument"

Tags: flutter, dart, recaptcha, dart-pub, recaptcha-v3

[`error image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdmgD.png)

I am facing problems with adding Recaptcha in the app and i dont understand what to do further.
please help me with this.

```
RecaptchaVerifier(
          size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
          theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
          onSuccess: (){

            print('reCAPTCHA Completed!');

            if(!resend){
              nextPosition();
            }

            setState(() {
              _showResend = false;
            });
          },
          onError: (FirebaseAuthException error){

            QuickHelp.showAppNotificationAdvanced(
                context: context,
                title: "error".tr(),
                message: error.message);
          },
          onExpired: () {

            QuickHelp.showAppNotificationAdvanced(
                context: context,
                title: "error".tr(),
                message: "auth.recaptcha_expired".tr());
```

Comment: You need to provide the `auth` parameter to the RecaptchaVerifier constructor.

Comment: how can I do that? can you please help me with this?